# Remover a última vírgula de um array de um While

Tags: php, csv

Estou tentando remover a ultima virgula de um Array mas não estou conseguindo.

Tenho um arquivo CSV em que eu faço a leitura e retiro um array com um código para ser utilizado em uma Where de uma Query sql.
Estou utilizando **substr($number_Aut,0,-1)** mas não está funcionando.

Segue o código:

```
<?
while(! feof($CSVfp)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($CSVfp, 1000, ";");


    $number_Aut =  "'$data[13]','"; //Pego o código desejado no arquivo CSV e adiciono Aspas simples e virgula
    if ($data[13] != '') { //Verifico se entre as aspas não tem campos Vazios
    echo substr($number_Aut,0,-1); //Elimino a ultima virgula do ARRAY MAS NÃO ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO
}


?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data[4])); ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $data[11]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $data[13]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $data[2]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $data[9]; ?>/<?php echo $data[10]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo number_format( $data[8], 2, ',', '.'); ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo number_format( $data[17], 2, ',', '.'); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php


    }
?>
```

Comment: Não seria substr($number_Aut,0,-3); ?

Comment: O ($number_Aut,0,-2) tira todas as virgulas
O ($number_Aut,0,-3) tira a ',

Comment: se tem o exemplo desse arquivo ?

Comment: pergunta besta, mas o seu CSV esta delimitado por `,` ou `;`?

Comment: outra coisa, aqui voce adiciona a virgula `$number_Aut =  "'$data[13]','";` 2 linhas depois voce tenta remover a ultima virgula, que acabou de adicionar. Nao ficou muito claro, se puder explicar melhor o que esta querendo fazer facilita muito.

Comment: Meu arquivo é demilitado por ; Em uma determinada linha retiro o ; e substituo por ' ', para jogar no where de uma query até ai tudo bem a dificuldade está sendo em retirar a ultima virgula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você diz no comentário do seu código **//Elimino a ultima virgula do ARRAY MAS NÃO ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO** na verdade você está eliminando a ultima aspas simples.

```
$var="";
if (($handle = fopen("http://dominio.com/Satellite.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
             $number_Aut =  "'$data[$c]','"; //Pego o código desejado no arquivo CSV e adiciono Aspas simples e virgula
             if ($data[$c] != '') { //Verifico se entre as aspas não tem campos Vazios
              $var.= substr($number_Aut,0,-1); //AQUI ESTÁ ELIMINANDO UMA ASPA SIMPLES
             }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$var= substr($var,0,-1); //AQUI ELIMINA A ULTIMA VIRGULA
echo $var;
```

O arquivo Satellite.csv é como mostra a figura abaixo:

[image: arquivo satelite.csv]

Comment: Fiz exatamente como está o seu exemplo deu certo em partes ele tirou a ultima virgula porem começou a replicar os resultados. conforme o exemplo abaixo:
'1','1','1' '2','2','2' '5','5','5' '6','6','6' '7','7','7' '8','8','8' '9','9','9' '10','10','10'

Comment: @Shaolin Fantastic editei a pergunta fazendo um while e deu certo!

Comment: Percebi que a estrutura do seu While estava um pouco diferente da minha segui exatamente o seu exemplo e deu certo!
Muito Obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi direito o seu problema é somente em eliminar uma vírgula no final da string se for só isso tente:

```
rtrim($number_Aut,',')
```

Porém pelo seu código acredito que tenha que tirar o ' também, pois você está acrescentando virgula e aspas:

```
rtrim(rtrim($number_Aut, "'"),",")
```

Comment: Até aqui não sei se resolveu o problema do autor da pergunta, mas um upvoto por me apresentar a algo que nunca tinha visto antes.

Comment: Gostei da solução mas tentei utilizar e não deu certo o primeiro apaga todas as virgulas e o segundo apaga a ultima aspa e as virgulas